# Upload a file to a chatter feed in Apex: API 36

Tags: apex, chatter, feeditem, chatter-file

I'm trying to upload a File to a Chatter feed using Apex API 36.  It is straightforward in API 35, and Salesforce provides the code below.  However it doesn't compile in API 36.  Does anyone have a code snippet that does what the code below does but works in API 36?

```
ConnectApi.FeedItemInput input = new ConnectApi.FeedItemInput();
input.subjectId = 'me';

ConnectApi.ContentCapabilityInput contentInput = new ConnectApi.ContentCapabilityInput();
contentInput.title = 'Title';

ConnectApi.FeedElementCapabilitiesInput capabilities = new ConnectApi.FeedElementCapabilitiesInput();
capabilities.content = contentInput;

input.capabilities = capabilities;

String text = 'These are the contents of the new file.';
Blob myBlob = Blob.valueOf(text);
ConnectApi.BinaryInput binInput = new ConnectApi.BinaryInput(myBlob, 'text/plain', 'fileName');

ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElement(Network.getNetworkId(), input, binInput);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it figured out, turns out you just use ContentVersion to upload a File:

```
    // ContentVersion is how you upload a file!
    ContentVersion version = new ContentVersion();
    version.Title='Mah File';
    version.PathOnClient = 'C:\\mahfile.txt';
    version.VersionData = Blob.valueOf('DummyFile');
    insert version;

    // After you insert the ContentVersion object, a base 'ContentDocument' is established
    // The ID of the ContentDocument is what you need to attach the file to the Chatter post.
    version = [SELECT ID,ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE ID=:version.id];

    // Form a basic post attached to our own feed.
    ConnectApi.FeedItemInput feedItem = new ConnectApi.FeedItemInput();
    feedItem.subjectId = 'me'; // This can also be an objectID to post the file to.

    // Now connect the feeditem to our already uploaded file.
    feedItem.capabilities = new ConnectAPI.FeedElementCapabilitiesInput();
    feedItem.capabilities.files = new ConnectAPI.FilesCapabilityInput();
    feedItem.capabilities.files.items = new List<ConnectAPI.FileIdInput>();
    ConnectAPI.FileIdInput attachFile = new ConnectAPI.FileIDInput();

    //**** Here is where we attach the specific file to the post!
    attachFile.id = version.contentDocumentid; 
    feedItem.capabilities.files.items.add(attachFile);

    // Execute the posting
    ConnectApi.FeedElement feedElement = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElement(Network.getNetworkId(), feedItem);
```

In the end though, I ditched the ConnectAPI and used the code below.  Seemed more straightforward to me and works in unit tests.  (The ConnectAPI requires unit tests to use SeeAllData=true which is a deal breaker for me.)

```
   // Upload the file
    ContentVersion version = new ContentVersion();
    version.Title='Mah File';
    version.PathOnClient = 'C:\\mahfile.txt';
    version.VersionData = Blob.valueOf('DummyFile');
    insert version;

    // Insert a simple post
    FeedItem post = new FeedITem();
    post.body = 'File Upload';
    post.ParentID = UserInfo.getUserID();
    insert post;

    // Associate the file with the post
    FeedAttachment postAttachment = new FeedAttachment();
    postAttachment.FeedEntityId = post.id;
    postAttachment.Type = 'Content';
    postAttachment.RecordId = version.id;
    insert postAttachment;
```

Comment: Testing ConnectApi Code doesn't necessarily mean your Test Class requires `@isTest(SeeAllData=true)`: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/connectAPI_TestingApex.htm